# INFORMIX ESQL/C 2.10.06E for MS-DOS 6.22 or 5.0

Tags: informix

Anyone know where I can get a copy of ESQL/C 2.10 which will work with INFORMIX-SQL 2.10.06E running on MS-DOS 5.0 or 6.22?.. I would also need to find Microsoft C compiler Version 6.

Comment: Would you not consider using FreeDos http://www.freedos.org?

Comment: Check here.. http://dev.eiffel.com/Installing_Microsoft_C_compiler_6.1_and_older, judging by the comments on the page, MS C compiler v6 is on that bundled package?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer will be 'nowhere legitimately', or that's almost certainly the case.  To the best of my recollection, the 2.10 products were released in 1987; the 2.10.03 (Unix) and 2.10.06 (DOS) products were likely released either in 1987 or perhaps as late as 1988.  As you already know, this is seriously antique software you are asking about.

If you are really lucky, you might find someone who still has the software, but you will indeed be lucky to find it at all.

Comment: is there anyone out there who has developed legacy MS-DOS based applications between 1987 to 1992 with INFORMIX-SQL, ESQL/C ver. 2.10.06E for MS-DOS?.. If you still have copies of the ESQL/C for DOS in your archives, I would be interested in it!

Answer (score 1):

YES - I have a copy of the origan Informix 2.10.06E 5 1/4" disks.  I am not sure how we can get in touch with one another.

Comment: I already have ISQL 2.10.06E, what I'm looking for is the ESQL/C 2.10 for MS-DOS that goes with the ISQL.

Comment: Sorry, I miss interpreted the question. I never purchased the ESQL/C "stuff" from Informix. It seems like I have been able to everything I need by just using the ISQL program. For VERY special items I use MS BASIC for DOS and dump the data into a file using the "SYSTEM PSACEGO" command and then display it using the Basic programming language. I will check at work and see if I own a version the ESQL/C but I do not remember buying it

Comment: thank you.. that's funny, I also use ACE to create load files.